# The controller with the name 'MyPageController' is not registered Error (Angular1.5.3)

Tags: angularjs, angular1.6

I,m working on a quite old project which using Angular1.5.3 and now I want to add a new component. I have configed everything as the other component, now the newpage can be display(.html wroks fine) , but the data is not loaded(controller). and I got the error:

`The controller with the name 'MyPageController' is not registered`

here is some code of the project:

in mypage.controller.js:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('forecastAngular')
    .controller('MypageController', MypageController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function MyPageController($scope, $rootScope, $state, $http, $timeout, usSpinnerService, dataFactory, $q, CommonServices, baseUrl) { 
... 
}
```

and in the index.route.js:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('forecastAngular')
    .config(routerConfig);

  /** @ngInject */
  function routerConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('mypage', {
        url: '/mypage',
        views: {
          'body': {
            templateUrl: 'app/myPage/mypage.html',
            controller: 'MypageController',
          }
        },
        data: {
          authorizedRoles: ['Admin', 'Manager', 'Director', 'Registered User', 'HR'],
          menuName: "mypage",
          isShowSearch: false,
          isShowDomain: false
        }
      });
}
```

and I also searched for this problem , someone said inject the controller use :

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyController', [function() {
  // ...
}]);
```

but I tried . not work for me . and the other component is config  like what I have paste above. and it works fine.

can any one tell me how can I register the controller in right way?

Comment: I don't see any controller named XXXController declared anywhere in the code you posted. I also don't see any function MyPageController being defined. Only UtforcastController, but which is never used anywhere. The actual code and the actual error matter. Post that instead of some imaginary code/error.

Comment: sorry , the file name is `mypage.html` , `mypage.controller.js` . I think the first charactor shuold be uppercase, so I use ` function MypageController` to inject function

Answer (score 1):

The function's name is wrong.

```
.controller('MyPageController', MyPageController);
```

Should be:

```
.controller('MyPageController', UtforcastController);
```

This function `MyPageController` does not exist.

Comment: sorry , but `UtforcastController ` is 'MyPageController'  , I don't want to expose my project's content , so I renamed it. In my project , the name is uniform.

Answer (score 0):

you said your module name is `forecastAngular`, but in another code, later on you created another module, which reference to no other, and it does create an empty controller

### Note:

`module(x)` is getter

`module(x, [])` is setter

So you trying to get a module that you may not defined in here:

```
angular
    .module('forecastAngular')
    .config(routerConfig);
```